# How can I change the touch anchor point of a sprite in SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I am creating a game in SpriteKit. It is similar to Air Hockey. When I touch the player's sprite to move it on the screen, I want the mallet/player sprite to be slightly above where I am touching. I would do this so that the mallet is easier to see. How can I easiest accomplish this?

Comment: On touch offset the why access. If memory serves you probably want to create an action. Alternatively, create another version of your mallet and make the sprite with the offset. And render that when touched

Comment: This implementation depends a lot on the effect you want to achieve, it could be a string that holds the sprite with a SKConstraint or it could be a time delay effect with SKActions. Can you be more specific about the effect you do you want to accomplish?